# BTEQ Export to csv file in UNIX

Tags: unix, header, teradata, export-to-csv, leading-zero

I am trying to export some records from a teradata table into a csv file using BTEQ Export.

While doing this I face 3 issues:
1. The leading zeroes of few columns get dropped. Please help as to how I can retain them.
2. I am not sure how to make the Headers bold, to make it look better.
3. Is it possible to put Grid lines, only in the records which contain data?

Please do not suggest to use Teradata Export. I need to use UNIX.

Thanks,
Aswath

Answer (score 2):

1. Leading zeros are added with a explicit format-phrase
   ( see [Formatting Characters for Non-Monetary Numeric Information](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference%2FB035-1143-160K%2Fzcj1472241389161.html%23wwID0E32BR))

   `select 4 (format '999,99') ;`
2. There are no terminal capabilities built in `Basic Teradata Query`.  `bteq` is mainly built for commandline usage with some basic reporting/formating abilties. You may add terminal escape codes in your SQL query, but I wouldn't recommend it. Especially, because you mention `BTEQ export` (I assume to a file).
3. The `.set separator '|'` command may help, but I doubt that you can get `grid lines`, assuming you want horizontal and vertical lines between your data.  By the way, creating a csv file with grid lines is somehow contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

`Unix` is an operating system, `TPT` or `FastExport` are programs *running* on an OS like Unix, exactly like `BTEQ`.

There's a [CSV function](https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_151K/CSV.html) to create delimited/quoted data.

But as @ULick already stated, `csv` doesn't have *grid lines*  or *bold headers*.